# Django CKEditor 404 image not found

Tags: django, ckeditor

On my Django admin panel, I can upload an image using CKEditor. However, the image doesn't apear and it return a 404 not found on the image file path.

Actually, my image files  are available on a dedicated url : media.mysite.com

But, CKEditor is trying to GET the file from mywebsite.com/media/uploads/..., so this is normal that I get a 404 error.

What is the good parameter to do for telling to CKEditor to use media.mysite.com to get any images ?

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/var/www/media/mysite/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"


CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'height': 300,
        'width': '100%',
    },
}
```

I visited many topics, but I found no answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding an alias in my apache vhost :

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/media/
```

So, when CKEDITOR is trying to access on mywebsite.com/media/upload, it's redirected on a specific folder "/var/www/media/".

This is a good workaround